# Mencoder cannot initialize video driver en batch (Windows 7 ultimate)

Tags: windows, batch

es mi primera pregunta en Stackoverflow. Tengo unos AVI en una carpeta que dese0 convertir a MP4. El asunto es que cuando llamo a mencoder.exe muestra un error. La línea de comandos que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
mencoder.exe video.avi  -mc 0 -of rawvideo -ovc x264 -oac pcm -o video.264 -x264encopts deblock=1,1:bframes=5:frameref=5:threads=auto:b_pyramid:nofast_pskip:nopsnr:bitrate=268:pass=2:8x8dct:weight_b:mixed_refs:me=umh:bime:partitions=all:subq=6:brdo:trellis=1  -nosound  -vf harddup
```

Y en error que recibo es el siguiente:

```
MEncoder Sherpya-SVN-r24537-4.2.1 (C) 2000-2007 MPlayer Team
CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3000+ (Family: 15, Model: 95, Stepping: 2)
CPUflags: Type: 15 MMX: 1 MMX2: 1 3DNow: 1 3DNow2: 1 SSE: 1 SSE2: 1
Compiled with runtime CPU detection.
success: format: 0  data: 0x0 - 0xd7b1000
AVI file format detected.
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
[aviheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
VIDEO:  [XVID]  704x528  12bpp  29.970 fps  1157.3 kbps (141.3 kbyte/s)
[V] filefmt:3  fourcc:0x44495658  size:704x528  fps:29.97  ftime:=0.0334
Opening video filter: [expand osd=1]
Expand: -1 x -1, -1 ; -1, osd: 1, aspect: 0.000000, round: 1
Opening video filter: [harddup]
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
VDec: vo config request - 704 x 528 (preferred colorspace: Planar YV12)
VDec: using Planar I420 as output csp (no 1)
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
x264 [info]: using SAR=1/1
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 3DNow!
x264 [error]: ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file
x264_encoder_open failed.
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.

Exiting...
```

La idea es ponerlo en un batch, porque son mas de  100 videos que quiero convertir. ¿Alguna idea?

Estoy utilizando Windows 7 Ultimate, y el RealAnime6 usa la misma línea de comandos para codificar sin problemas.

Comment: podrías escribir todo el fichero .bat en lugar de sólo esa línea? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que mencoder no encuentra el fichero de estadísticas.

Lo busca porque has especificado la opción `pass=2`, que se utiliza en codificaciones de 2 pasadas.

Este sistema primeramente comprime el vídeo recopilando estadísticas `pass=1`. Después el vídeo se descarta ya que lo importante es este fichero.

Después, con `pass=2` se utiliza el fichero de estadísticas creado en el anterior paso para comprimir el vídeo final (tomando las mejores decisiones acorde al fichero de estadísticas)

En ejemplo básico sobre como codificar con este sistema sería este:

```
REM Primera pasada, pass=1 y -o nul para descartar el video procesado
mencoder "entrada.mkv" -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=3000:pass=1 -oac copy -o nul

REM Segunda pasada, pass=2 y -o nombre del fichero que queremos
mencoder "entrada.mkv" -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=3000:pass=2 -oac copy -o "salida.mkv"
```

Si no te quieres complicar, puedes utilizar [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) que permite hacer esto mismo de una manera más fácil. Puedes ademas establecer un grupo de vídeos a codificar para que no tengas que ir uno a uno.

Espero que te sirva.